# Sharepoint Online - JSON column formatting

Tags: json, sharepoint, conditional-formatting

I have the following code given by Michael Han that is working just fine. It formats a number like '2030' to be '20:30'

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": {
    "operator": "+",
    "operands": [
      "=substring(toString(@currentField),0,2)",
      ":",
      "=substring(toString(@currentField),2,4)"
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to use this column as a lookup column for another list, so I pasted this code and replaced **@currentField** with **@currentField.LookupValue** in the new lookup column as mentioned in https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/declarative-customization/column-formatting.md

The result is just showing "**:**". What do I have to do to make it work?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use **@currentField.lookupValue** instead of **@currentField.LookupValue**, the first character of lookupValue should be lowercase.
And the code only works if the field in the parent list is Single line of text.

[image]

If the type of field in the parent list is Number, you need to change the code to this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": {
    "operator": "+",
    "operands": [
      "=substring(toString(@currentField.lookupValue),0,1)",
      "=substring(toString(@currentField.lookupValue),2,3)",
      ":",
      "=substring(toString(@currentField.lookupValue)3,5)"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Michael, please take a look at the pictures and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: I think you use "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" in look up column settings. For these columns just use @currentField that would work.

Comment: Works just fine. Thanks.